# Parse a local CSV with JavaScript or using Rails+JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I have a Rails application that has some JavaScript that needs to parse CSVs and make some AJAX calls based on each record.

I'd like to just load the local CSV directly into browser memory and have the JavaScript parse it and make the required AJAX calls but I haven't found a cross-browser, dependable way to accomplish this (I need to support cruddy old IE6).

I could upload the CSV to my rails application but I plan on hosting the application on Heroku and as I understand it, Heroku doesn't allow you to edit the files system(create files). I could also write the CSVs to a database but these CSVs are large 10mb+ and I imagine I will undoubtedly suffer performance costs in doing this.

Is my best option pushing the CSV to Rails and having Rails respond with a JSON or string version of the CSV? This seems somewhat computationally expensive given the size of these CSVs. I'd prefer to keep it on the client-side. If that's the case can someone point me to an example on how to accomplish this or something similar?

**Edit: I don't want users to have to copy and paste these CSVs into a textfield manually.**

**Edit2: Also, I'm aware of the security restrictions on accessing the local filesystem via JS. A solid flash embed is an acceptable option.**